# Change permissions on a user folder - will this shell script work?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I am trying to change permissions on a user's folder that is not an administrator. I was told to run this script:

```
{
    sudo chflags -R nouchg,nouappnd ~ $TMPDIR..
    sudo chown -R $UID:staff ~ $_
    sudo chmod -R u+rwX ~ $_
    chmod -R -N ~ $_
} 2> /dev/null
```

But I am afraid that it will `chown` my user folder, instead of the user I am trying to fix.

Comment: Why not just change the permissions on the folder as you like? `sudo chmod ...` or `sudo chown ...` or what-have-you. Seems like a much better idea then running some random stuff you found online that you don't understand.

Comment: Replace `~` with `~user` where `user` is the account of the non-admin user.

Comment: And `$UID` needs to be the uid of the target user. (All-caps variable names are in a namespace [reserved for variables meaningful to the system](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html); if that's actually intended to be pre-populated with a different user ID rather than the current ID, it's not a good choice of names).

Comment: (I'd also advise against using `$_` in any scenario that's at all sensitive -- too easy for it to get a new value from a trap, a hook, an extra line added for logging/debugging purposes, etc)